# Generate random number with different digits (digits will be as many as the number the user entered) in Java

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a random number with as many digits as the user enters. All of these digits should be different from each other. I can't do it with arrays because I learned Java in methods, so what should I do? I thought of doing it this way but up to `k == 10` is too long. Is there a shorter way? If the user enters the value of `a` as 8, I have to create a number with 8 different digits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("a: ");
    int a = scn.nextInt();
    random(a);
}

public static void random(int k) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rand;
    if (k == 1) {
        rand = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        System.out.println(rand);
    } else if (k == 2) {
        rand = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 90);
        int digit1 = rand / 10;
        int digit2 = rand % 10;
        while (digit1 == digit2) {
            if (digit1 == 0) {
                digit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rand);
    } else if (k == 3) {
        rand = 100 + (int) (Math.random() * 900);
        int digit1 = rand / 100;
        int digit2 = (rand / 10) % 10;
        int digit3 = rand % 10;
        while (digit1 == digit2 || digit1 == digit3 || digit2 == digit3) {
            if (digit1 == digit2 || digit2 == digit3) {
                digit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            }
            if (digit1 == digit3 || digit2 == digit3) {
                digit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to recall this exact question being asked yesterday. Why didn't you edit the older question if you wanted it reopened? Unless somebody else asked it.

Comment: What if I enter `11`?

Comment: But on the decimal numeral system you only have10 different digits...10 is max I guess?

Comment: There are 10 digits from 0 to 9. The user will receive an error message as the digits will be repeated after entering a number greater than 10 @BoristheSpider

Comment: Yes it is correct @aran

Comment: I am asking for the first time @NomadMaker

Comment: Then you should search the answers here to see the older ones. This isn't an uncommon homework problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Characters` to allow a simple concatenation of the required digits. Then, if needed, you can convert it to numeric. **3 steps**:

---

**1.** **Store the numbers in a `List`:**

```
List<Character> numbers = Arrays.asList('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
```

---

**2**. **`Shuffle`** the **list using a `Random` instance** previously declared and initialized.

*Edit* - *previously I told about creating a new `Random()` to pass as argument to the suffle method. As  [***@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) correctly points on the comment, **this is not necessary and just worsens the performance**. Besides, as the comment also states, creating multiple instances in a short period of time will lead to repeated sequences, as the random generator relies on the system clock. So just reuse the same instance:*

```
/*on variables declaration*/
final Random r = new Random();
...

Collections.shuffle(numbers, r);
```

---

**3**.  **Get the required digits**, by **concatenating the `Characters`**.

Finally, parse the resulting `String` to numeric. *I assume that*  `(>0 requiredDigits <11)`

***Beware of leading zeros**. If the first choosen character is 0, the `parseInt` method will logically remove it, returning a numeric value with an incorrect number of required digits. If more than a digit is requested, turn the leading zero into a trailing zero, by **"moving" it to the end of the string**. If just one digit is required `parseInt` will return `0`, so no issues in that case.*

```
 String result="";

 for (int i=0;i<requiredDigits;i++)
    result+=numbers.get(i);

 if (requiredDigits>1 && result.charAt(0)==('0'))
      result = result.replace("0", "") +'0';

int numericResult = Integer.parseInt(result);
```

---

***Resume***

You **avoid constant calls to random number generations**, the only "heavy" operation being the list *shuffle*. As its size is small, this operation will also be a *really cheap one*. This approach avoids constant numeric operations and works with a very limited list of decimal digits stored as `Characters`.

An optimization in order to **avoid half of the shuffle random operations** would be using one of these for even requests (2nd, 4th,...):

**1.**  `Collections.reverse(numbers);`

**2.**  Iterate the previously shuffled list in reverse order

```
    for (int i=requiredDigits-1; i>=0; i--)
        result+=numbers.get(i);
```

This way, only one shuffle operation would be enough for **2 requests**.

Comment: I would declare `numbers` as `List` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks for that...Dunno how I'm able to "correctly" declare them in production code and fail this way in an answer...

Comment: No problem. Part of the good practice, as I understand it, is that you should declare objects as the appropriate interface whenever possible otherwise the code might end up being tightly coupled. The code should support loose-coupling whenever possible.

Comment: I swear I always declare the abstract type and only specify the implementation when instantiating it...but List.of has confused me here...

Comment: You should not use `new Random()` as an inline value; `Random` instances are expensive to create, and behavior will be poor (possibly repeated sequences) if they're created close together. Instead, the `Random` should be initialized once (generally in a final field) and reused.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thanks for pointing this out. You are totally correct; I edited my answer so the mechanism reuses the same instance. Sincere thanks!

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- besides this answer, also thanks for correcting me regarding the System.out operation and the string concatenation; You were correct indeed as well. Thanks for your patience while explaining it, sincerely!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you can't use arrays, I am assuming you can't use `Lists` either since they are similar.  So here is a possible alternative.

- Initialize a string to the digits.
- generate a random number based on the string length.
- get the digit at the location and add to the final value.
- remove the digit from the string using substring methods.
- continue until 8 digits have been selected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(getUnique(8));
}
```

Prints something like this.

```
41985372
68942750
42978135
67829345
24970361
17209568
14759862
52083769
63420871
75631049
```

The generating method.

```
        
public static long getUnique(int ndigits) {
    if (ndigits < 1 || ndigits > 10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Number of digits must be between 1 and 10 inclusive");
    }
    String digits = "0123456789";
    long num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ndigits; i++) {
        int d = (int) (Math.random() * digits.length());
        // make certain first digit is not a 0.
        // otherwise, number will only have `ndigits - 1` digits.
        if (d == 0 && i == 0) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        // convert character to an int and "append" to the num.
        num = num * 10 + digits.charAt(d) - '0';

        // effectively delete the just used digit from the string.
        digits = digits.substring(0, d) + digits.substring(d + 1);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Additional explanation of the statement `num = num * 10 + digits.charAt(d) - '0';`

- initialize num to 0
- say the character is a '3'.  That is 063 in octal.
- subtract '0' from it to get an int value of 3.
- first time thru num = num * 10 + 3 = 3.
- next digit is a '4' - '0' = 4
- num = num * 10 + 4 = 3 * 10 + 4 = 34.
- next digit is a '5'-'0' = 5
- num = num * 10 + 5 = 34 * 10 + 5 = 345.
  continue in this fashion.

Comment: Nice answer! Not only does it meet the requirement precisely but also use does it elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

class random{
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int upperbound = 10;
    String s_val = "";
    int i = 0;
    int user_req_len = 10;
    int val;
    while(s_val.length()<user_req_len){
        val = rand.nextInt(upperbound); 
        if((s_val.indexOf(String.valueOf(val))==-1)){
            s_val = s_val+""+val;
        }
    }
    long value;
    value = Long.parseLong(s_val);
    System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

This will work