# Looking at different or same digits of a number in java

Tags: java, unique

How do I know if all the digits of a 7-digit number are different? For instance, I am generating a 7-digit random number and this number is 7493759. This number can be 6,8 or 10 digits. How do I check if the digits of this number are the same?

Comment: Do you want to check if number contains of only one repeating digit like `111111` or `22222222` or `3333333333333`? In other words that *all* "digits of this number are the same"?

Comment: This sounds very much related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65346434/1552534)

Comment: // convert character to an int and "append" to the num.
        num = num * 10 + digits.charAt(d) - '0';    what exactly did you do here? What does it do to write "-'0 '"? @WJS

Comment: @user14846862 I modified my other answer with a detailed explanation at the end.  Check it out.  If you have more questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `int` to a `String` and the count of distinct characters in it. If the count is greater than or equal to the length of the string, the digits are not unique.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 7493759;
        // Test
        System.out.println(areDigitsUnique(7493759));
        System.out.println(areDigitsUnique(1234567));
    }

    static boolean areDigitsUnique(int num) {
        String strNum = String.valueOf(num);
        return strNum.chars().distinct().count() >= strNum.length();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

If a `n`-digit number have the same digits, then it is divisible by `11..11` (n 1's):

```java
public static boolean areDigitsTheSame(int n){
        int d = String.valueOf(n).length();
        int divisor = 0;
        while (d-->0){
            divisor=divisor*10 + 1;
        }
        return n % divisor == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short description of the code:

- Take input as String. (If an input is not in String, convert it into String)
- Convert the string into char array
- Create a set and put all the elements of char array into set
- If the length of char array is same as the size of set then all elements are different (Set doesn't contain duplicates)

import java.util.*;

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = input.next();
        char[] c = num.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> set  = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            set.add(c[i]);
        }
        if(c.length == set.size()) System.out.println("Digits are different");
        else System.out.println("Some digits are same.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to check if a digit in Your number is repeated You can make a String out of the number and then loop over the characters comparing them to each other. For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int integer = 1234556;
        String number = String.valueOf(integer);

        System.out.println(numberRepetition(number));

    }
    
    static boolean numberRepetition(CharSequence s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Comparing: " + s.charAt(i) + " to: " + s.charAt(j));
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```